# How to speed up query execution in oracle when the tables are joined

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

I already asked this question, but it was closed by the system.
I have the code, after I added a very important part to it, it is on a page where a lot of data takes 3-5 minutes to load for a very long time. Here is a demo where the highlighted part through https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=892dcef2af2f606a7c31d15dfcba7314 which it works for a long time. Is it possible to optimize the code so that it does not respond? I tried through the tables indices, but it didn't work, I would be grateful for the help.The whole problem with this part of the code

```html
    AND rep.id not in ( select o.id 
  from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o,
       IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION parent
 where o.parent = parent.parent
   and parent.key = 'reader'
   and parent.VALUE_STRING !=  txn.reader_value_string)
```

This code corresponds to the fact that when a connection occurs, I do not want to join the table if the reader is not suitable for me.
I wish I didn't have a subquery at all, and the result left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to suggest here something without trace (the best option) or execution plan for such cases.

All I can see here, the subquery can be rewritten as the following

```
select id 
  from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o,
       IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION parent
 where o.parent = parent.parent
   and parent.key = 'reader'
   and VALUE_STRING !=  txn.reader_value_string;
```

But I'm not sure if this makes any sence to join the table with itself using same column. Perhaps you wanted to join o.parent with u.id?

```
... where o.parent in 
         (select u.id /* <-- */ from ...
```

As I said if this wouldn't help, provide us please the query plan or trace for that query

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206854/discussion-on-answer-by-ekochergin-how-to-speed-up-query-execution-in-oracle-whe).

Comment: Hi @SamuelLiew , thanks for that. Never knew there is a chat here.

How do I start it next time?

Comment: When there are more than 10 comments in the discussion, this feature will be available automatically. After the last comment.

Comment: @АндрійГавриляк never knew that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use second sub-query here :

```
select . . .
from . . . 
where . . . and 
      not exists (select 1
                  from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o
                  where o.key = 'reader' and
                        u.VALUE_STRING <> txn.reader_value_string and
                        rep.id = o.id
                 );
```

Comment: And maybe my request was reworked without a subquery, but what was the answer ??